# How to change TextView size in scene transition animation?

Tags: android, animation

Please help me with scene transition animation settings.

This is my idea:
[image]

When I click on the `TextView` (FirstActivity) I want share this `TextView` to SecondActivity with view size changing and moving.

When I open (or close) SecondActivity my `TextView` moving (by arrow #1 or #2) but **without** size changing. And this looked ugly.

**This is my code:**

**Theme** (I use this theme for both FirstActivity and SecondActivity):

```
<style name="AppTheme.MaterialAnimation.SharedViews">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@transition/enter_shared_ui</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@transition/exit_shared_ui</item>
</style>
```

**enter_shared_ui**.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="4000"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_cubic">

        <changeBounds />
    </transitionSet>
```

**exit_shared_ui**.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="4000"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_cubic">

        <changeBounds />
    </transitionSet>
```

**How to change TextView size changing in my scene transition animation?**

**UPDATE:**

This code for launching SecondActivity:

```
    private fun openSecondScreen() {
    val intent = Intent(this, SharedUIFinishActivity::class.java)
    ... // add another views to Pair
    val thirdPair = Pair(tvSharedUISelect as View, getString(R.string.shared_ui_text))
    val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                    ... thirdPair)

    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
}
```

And for both `TextView`'s I use the same transition name.

Answer (score 1):

To make the `SharedElementTransition` to work, you have to set the same transition names to both the TextView in Activity1 and Activity2.

make sure the names are same, so that the framework can know to which the transition has to happen.

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:transitionName="my_transition"/>
```

in Activity1 to start Activity2

```
startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), textView, textView.getTransitionName()).toBundle());
```

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post and add code for launching SecondActivity - but I already do it.

Comment: Ok, then maybe this is what you are looking for. https://medium.com/bcgdv-engineering/changing-text-size-and-color-in-shared-element-activity-transition-a31d932b7600